# Get the length of object in json

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, ajax, object

I'm building a web app that displays the next buses from a certain stop.

It uses the TransportAPI and from there I get a JSON file: https://transportapi.com/v3/uk/bus/stop/450023470/live.json?app_id=221cce2f&app_key=d209929236fc97196775650c2bdb639e&group=route&limit=2&nextbuses=yes

The JSON is in an array and I'm having difficulty access the data inside of 29

```
{
  "atcocode": "450023470",
  "smscode": "45023470",
  "request_time": "2017-05-11T11:57:51Z",
  "name": "Headingley Campus",
  "stop_name": "Headingley Campus",
  "bearing": "N",
  "indicator": "",
  "locality": "Beckett Park, Leeds",
  "departures": {
    "29": [
      {
        "mode": "bus",
        "line": "29",
        "line_name": "29",
        "direction": "Student Village",
        "operator": "FL",
        "date": "2017-05-11",
        "expected_departure_date": "2017-05-11",
        "aimed_departure_time": "13:05",
        "expected_departure_time": "13:05",
        "best_departure_estimate": "13:05",
        "source": "NextBuses",
        "dir": "inbound",
        "id": "https:\/\/transportapi.com\/v3\/uk\/bus\/route\/FL\/29\/inbound\/450023470\/2017-05-11\/13:05\/timetable.json?app_id=221cce2f&app_key=d209929236fc97196775650c2bdb639e",
        "operator_name": "First Leeds"
      }
```

the below works, but I won't always know what the value [29] is.

```
alert(obj['departures'][29].length);
```

How can I get the length without knowing the value?

full code below

```
$.ajax({
    type:"GET",
    dataType: 'JSONP',
    jsonpCallback: 'callback',
    url: "https://transportapi.com/v3/uk/bus/stop/450023470/live.json?app_id=221cce2f&app_key=d209929236fc97196775650c2bdb639e&group=route&limit=2&nextbuses=yes", 
    success: function(data) {
        var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(data));

alert(obj['departures'][29].length);

            //$("body").append(JSON.stringify(data['departures'][29][0]['line_name']));
            //alert(obj.departures.length);
        }, 
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(jqXHR.status);
        },

});
```

Comment: Just a naming thing; you're not getting the length of an object with that alert; you're getting the length of an array. Also, not sure why you're doing `jQuery.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(data))`, when `data` is already an object...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Object.keys(obj.departures)` will return the keys of `obj.departures`.  Based on your context, I assume there's only one key, which in your example is "29."

So simply replace "29" with `Object.keys(obj.departures)`:

```
obj.departures[Object.keys(obj.departures)].length
```

Do note that the code you posted shows a regular object, not a JSON.  JSON is a string representation of an object.

**Snippet:**

```js
var obj = {
  //...
  "departures": {
    "randomkey": [
      {
        "mode": "bus",
  //...        
      },
      {
        "mode": "automobile",
  //...        
      },
      {
        "mode": "train"
  //...        
      }
    ]
  }
}
console.log(obj.departures[Object.keys(obj.departures)].length);  //3
```

Comment: I find it odd that two answers that legitimately address the question got down voted. If it is of any encouragement, I gave you an upvote because it works.

Comment: Thanks, @Terry.  There may have been a legitimate reason for the downvote, but it's no help to you (or me) if no explanation is given for it.

Comment: Hi @RickHitchcock, thanks for this. I probably should have added a better snippet of my object as there are 2 keys in this example, 29 and 29x. Using your example how would I go about also getting bus 29x? Thanks

Comment: If there are always 2 keys, and the second key is equal to the first plus the letter "x", you can get the second one like this:  `obj.departures[Object.keys(obj.departures) + 'x'].length`.  Otherwise, one of the other posted answers may work better for you.

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate the object's properties:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(data); // Using native browser JSON parsing instead

if (obj.hasOwnProperty('departures')) { // Should validate just to be sure
    for (var i in obj['departures']) {
        console.log(i, obj['departures'][i], obj['departures'][i].length); // Or anything
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not interested in the actual key-names but just want to get the returned bus lines as an array you can convert the `departures`-object into an array by doing

```
var depArr=Object.values(dataObj.departures);
```

The `var n=depArr.length` will then give you the number of different bus lines being offered and `depArr[i].length` will give you the number of times given for each of the bus lines (`i = 0...(n-1)`).

Answer (score 0):

Try [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) , [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map?v=example) with `ES6` Arrow assignment.

```js
var jsonObj = {
"atcocode": "450023470",
"smscode": "45023470",
"request_time": "2017-05-13T18:42:12+01:00",
"bearing": "N",
"indicator": "",
"name": "Headingley Campus",
"locality": "Beckett Park, Leeds",
"stop_name": "Headingley Campus",
"departures": {
 "29": [
      {
        "mode": "bus",
        "line": "29",
        "line_name": "29",
        "direction": "Student Village",
        "operator": "FL",
        "date": "2017-05-11",
        "expected_departure_date": "2017-05-11",
        "aimed_departure_time": "13:05",
        "expected_departure_time": "13:05",
        "best_departure_estimate": "13:05",
        "source": "NextBuses",
        "dir": "inbound",
        "id": "https:\/\/transportapi.com\/v3\/uk\/bus\/route\/FL\/29\/inbound\/450023470\/2017-05-11\/13:05\/timetable.json?app_id=221cce2f&app_key=d209929236fc97196775650c2bdb639e",
        "operator_name": "First Leeds"
      }]
}
};

var res = Object.keys(jsonObj.departures).map(item => {return jsonObj.departures[item].length});

console.log(res);
```